# No graphics are displayed when I used ggplot2 in python?

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, pycharm

here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
from rpy2.robjects.lib import ggplot2
import numpy as np
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

x = np.random.uniform(0, 10, 10)
y = np.random.normal(10, 4, 10)
color = np.random.normal(20, 4, 10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x,
                   'y': y,
                   'color': color})
rdf = pandas2ri.py2ri(df)
# print(type(rdf))
pp = ggplot2.ggplot(rdf) + \
     ggplot2.aes_string(x='x', y='y', col='factor(color)') + \
     ggplot2.geom_point()
pp.plot()
```

Pycharm didn't  offer any mistakes, nothing was show but a white page.

Comment: python has it's own ggplot module now — http://ggplot.yhathq.com — and for what you're doing it'll serve your needs quite well. no need to bring in an R dependency. That code works fine in a python shell for me, tho, so I added a pycharm tag as it may be IDE related.

Comment: fwiw it also works fine in a jupyter notebook (though the plot is not inline for me).